# Android disable screen saver

Tags: android, screensaver

I'd like to disable screen saver while my appliction is running.
How it can be done? Where is the best place to disable / enable the screen saver? in the first activity? in the application.java?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The wake lock permission must be specified in the manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Then in the activity use the following to keep the screen on while the activity is running.

```
getWindow().addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Remember that unnecessarily keeping the screen on unnecessarily drains power from the user's device.

Comment: Any idea if this prevents the Google TV screen saver from coming up?

Comment: You actually don't need wake lock permission for this window flag, see: https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html

Answer (score 3):

You must also add:

**import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams;**