# Application For Google TV

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-tv

I am working on Google Android TV Application.

My application has to download images from a Social Networking Website and then play the images as a screen Saver when ever the Google Android TV is idle state.

Getting the images is not a problem, I've completed that.

I am unable to find any API's of Screen Saver or the Settings of Google API. I am unable to understand how can I pull the downloaded images to play it in screen saver.

Answer (score 0):

You need a timer which at certain interval check for [`onUserInteraction()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserInteraction%28%29), when user is not interacting you need to start your activity in full screen mode playing all the images.

Comment: What happens when user is watching a TV ? He is not interacting but just watching it for hours .. How can we detect it that time ? We cant play screen saver while he is watching ..

Answer (score 0):

Downloading images is easy using the [apache](http://hc.apache.org/) http apis to get the url and image but put these in an Async task. You can also load the image using something like [LazyList](http://androidsnips.blogspot.com/2010/08/lazy-loading-of-images-in-list-view-in.html). Once the image is downloaded you can then display it easily too with an Imageview in ad a timer checking for onUserInteraction() when the user is not active.

Also you might want to look into these questions and group answers:

[Android disable screen saver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6290094/346309)

[Application For Google TV](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13310965/346309)

[GoogleGroups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/7fv-BhOxkyc)

Comment: What happens when user is watching a TV ? He is not interacting but just watching it for hours .. How can we detect it that time ? We cant play screen saver while he is watching ..

Comment: Well I know my direcTV has a 4 hour timer if I don't do one thing for 4 hours then it will shut off.  You can take this approach and set the screen saver to something very long.  But if you are trying to figure out if the user is watching TV then all you have to check is the streams and see if he is streaming anything.